# Как выполнить деление суммы строки на каждый элемент строки?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Задание начального значения количества строк и столбцов
    {
        Source_DGV.RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Rows_NUD.Value);
        Source_DGV.ColumnCount = Convert.ToInt32(Cols_NUD.Value);
    }

    private void Rows_NUD_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Source_DGV.RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Rows_NUD.Value);
    }

    private void Cols_NUD_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Source_DGV.ColumnCount = Convert.ToInt32(Cols_NUD.Value);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int min_i, min_j;
        /*Заполнения матрицы */
        int[,] matr = new int[Source_DGV.RowCount, Source_DGV.ColumnCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < Source_DGV.RowCount; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < Source_DGV.ColumnCount; j++)
                matr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Source_DGV[j, i].Value);

        // сумма по строке
        int [] s = new int[Source_DGV.RowCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < Source_DGV.RowCount; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < Source_DGV.ColumnCount; j++)
                s[i]+= matr[i, j];

    }

}
```

[image: сама форма]

Comment: ну так и в чем проблема? У вас какой то код не работает?

Comment: чтобы разделить элемент на сумму строки, надо посчитать сумму строки, взять элемент и разделить. У вас по частям этот код уже есть

Comment: я не знаю как сделать деление каждого элемента строки на сумму

Comment: ну вы сумму по строке посчитали? Вам нужны такие же циклы, но вместо подсчета суммы выполнить деление.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начало правильное, просто добавьте еще этот код:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < Source_DGV.RowCount; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Source_DGV.ColumnCount; j++)
            matr[i, j]= matr[i, j]/s[i];
```